# Displaying two textboxes side by side in MVC3 form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view

I'm looking to arrange two textboxes side by side in an MVC view, as part of my form. How do I get the two textboxes to appear in the same line inside the view?

Comment: Text input elements are, by default, inline elements and will appear next to one another as long as there is space in whatever container they are in to display them side-by-side. If this isn't working for you,  you might want to include your HTML so we can see an example of what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default MVC style sheet will have elements under each other if you have used a scaffolded view.

Applying a float left to your elements will have them side by side.

Use your browser of choice's inspect element to find ids or classes of div to apply style to.

Answer (score 1):

Since they are inline elements, you would use the same principles as making sure two images remain on the same line.

- Don't line break or have them in separate block elements.
- Make sure there is room enough for them, by keeping their size small enough.